# Magento 1.9.x moving website from shared server to Amazon ec2 instance

Tags: magento, amazon-ec2, devops, magento-1.9

I was trying to move a Magento 1.9 store from a shared server to a an standalone server ( an Amazon EC2) instance.

I tried the following :
Created an ec2 instance where I migrated the database(using MySQL dump) and changed the core_config_data to allow access from the new IP address.
when copied my source code (www/public_html/*) to the new server my server gives and error.

Another approach was I used a preconfigured Magento image where I linked the database to the new store using MySQL dump and I was able to see all the products but as soon as I copied source code to allow the same frontend I was getting an error.

How can I properly migrate a Magento 1.9 store to AWS instance?

Answer (score 0):

You should deploy a new installation of magento and follow the step by step instructions mentioned in the article here https://www.islbd.com/resources/web-design-and-development/how-to-move-magento-from-one-server-to-another to import your 'old site'.

The second method should work for you.